# Void function (C language)

Tags: c, void

I'm trying to run a very simple code using a void function, but no matter what I try or some error occurs, or the program doesn't print what it was supposed to. The code is

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i,j;
    i = 1;
    j = 2;
    add(i, j);
    return 0;
}

void add(int i, int j) 
{
    printf("%d + %d = %d", i, j, (i+j));
}
```

I am trying to use void in other more complex program so I am using this very simple to discover how to make it.

Comment: What error message did you get? Please don't make us guess.

Comment: What's your problem? The code seems able to run! I may suggest you to declare the prototype of the `add()` function before the main. The prototype is: `void add(int i, int j);` ... Other suggestion is: `printf("%d + %d = %d\n"`

Comment: Keep in mind that if you don't give a return type to your function (or if it's implicit) your c compiler will assign `int` by default. This may give you some warnings

Answer (score 6):

You need to give a prototype (or definition) of a function before you use it in a program.

**Definition**

Shift the function `add` before `main` function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void add(int i, int j) 
{
   printf("%d + %d = %d", i, j , (i+j));

}

int main()
 {
     int i,j;
     i = 1;
     j=2;
     add( i, j);
     return 0;
 }
```

**Prototype**

```
#include <stdio.h>
void add(int,int);
int main()
{
    int i,j;
    i = 1;
    j = 2;
    add(i, j);
    return 0;
 }

void add(int i, int j) 
{
    printf("%d + %d = %d", i, j, (i+j));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Change the order so that `add` is read first

```
#include <stdio.h>

void add(int i, int j) 
{
    printf("%d + %d = %d", i, j, (i+j));
}

int main()
{
    int i,j;
    i = 1;
    j = 2;
    add(i, j);
    return 0;
}
```